# Throws exception when session of class getting null - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I have stored logged in user details when user login to the system. And I have reusing it on many pages of my application. But after idle time, when I'm using the application it throws an error like below. How can I solve this?

```
 public class GlobalVariables
{
    public  string login_user_name = string.Empty;
    public  string login_user_id = string.Empty;
    public  string login_user_role = string.Empty;
}  
 <sessionState mode="InProc" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" stateNetworkTimeout="30" sqlCommandTimeout="30" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>
```

When login, storing the login details to the Session["objGlobalVariableClass"] as below :

```
  GlobalVariables obj_GlobalVariables = new GlobalVariables();
  obj_GlobalVariables.login_user_id = userID;
  obj_GlobalVariables.login_user_name = user_name;
  obj_GlobalVariables.login_user_role = login_user_role;//getting from database
  Session["objGlobalVariableClass"] = obj_GlobalVariables;
```

On every other pages:

```
  GlobalVariables obj_GlobalVariables;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj_GlobalVariables= (GlobalVariables)Session["objGlobalVariableClass"];
        try
        {
            if (obj_erms_GlobalVariables == null)
            {
                string log_data = "GlobalVariable details are getting null  \r\n";
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // possibly do something here
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
     }
if(!IsPostBack)
{ 
lbl_username.Text = "Welcome " + obj_GlobalVariables.login_user_name;
}
```

But after idle time, system shows error when using this logged in user details. It' becomes null there. How can I redirect to login page if it gets null anywhere in the system?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger to see where it fails? Or follow the instructions on the error page to enable detailed error output

Comment: It fails when obj_GlobalVariables becomes null. It automatically becomes null after some idle time.

Comment: maybe after some time, some how you are loosing session, so you are loosing your variable stored in that session too, and until user wont refresh site (so PageLoad will trigger), you will have null there.

Comment: yes on config file I have set the  timeout="30" . So how can I auto redirect to login page if session becomes null ?It is not easy to check it  everywhere I'm using the above session variables. Is there any other way?

Comment: I didn't mean "when" does it fail, as in the overall scenario, i meant "where" as in the exact line of code.

Answer (score 0):

On web.config, I added below lines of code.

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" requireSSL="true" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>
```

This will auto logout the page when session time out. And hence that error will not come up.